# How to measure the height of a building from images using image processors?

Tags: image-processing, maps, mapkit

I need to get information of building heights. I'm trying to extract this information from Apple Maps using image processors. The image is in 3D and might be rotated.

How should I proceed to get the height of building by processing the image? The red line in the image is what I'm trying to measure.

[image: Height of this building]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Phtogrammetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry) is an industry that creates height maps from aerial shots or images like what you are trying to do.

Now to write your own image processor would be a task in itself considering (from what I can understand) that you would need to know the rotation Quaternion or Vector then have a standard reference size to go off of and do some 3d math from there - because in an Perspective image like that the building's height will be 'off' when looking at it from an orthographic view like the image - so you need to factor that in somehow.

I hope this gives you somewhat of an idea into how to do what you want to do. 
you can always try a different mapping API that already has height maps built in.

Cheers,
Demetry

Answer (score 0):

Mapkit won't give you the elevation data. But you could go for [Google Maps Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro).

Comment: You are correct, it doesn't give me elevation data. Google Maps Elevation API gives me the terrain elevation, I need the elevation in the top of the building (surface elevation) so that I can calculate the height of the building. Some reference: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5701/what-is-the-difference-between-dem-dsm-and-dtm

Comment: There's the ElevationService() object that gets the surface value. You can get the JS library for parses here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation and see an example in action here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-simple